# angular material pagination not working with expandable row

Tags: angular, html-table, pagination, angular-material, angular6

I'm trying to use angular material table with expandable rows with paginator, the problem is, with the custom connect MatTableDataSource used for the expandable row the pagination stops working, I didn't find the answers anywhere to the problem.

So, the test table data is given by this stub service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TableRow } from './table-row';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestTableService {

  private testData : TableRow[] = [
    {id:1, name:'pi', value:3.14},
    {id:2, name:'euler', value:2.71},
    {id:3, name:'Feigenbaum constant', value:2.50290},
    {id:4, name:'Mills constant', value:1.30637},
    {id:5, name:'one', value:1},
    {id:6, name:'square root of 2', value:1.41421}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  public getData() : Observable<TableRow[]>
  {
    return of(this.testData);
  }
}
```

the table component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TestTableService } from './../test-table.service';
import { TableRow } from './../table-row';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-table',
  templateUrl: './test-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-table.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*', visibility: 'visible' }))
    ]),
  ],
})
export class TestTableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableData : myDataSource<TableRow> = new myDataSource();
  columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'name','value'];
  isExpansionDetailRow = (i: number, row: Object) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');
  expandedElement = null;

  constructor(private testTable : TestTableService) { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.tableData.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  //@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testTable.getData()
      .subscribe(table => this.tableData.data = table);
    //this.tableData.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  expand(row){
    this.expandedElement = this.expandedElement == row ? null : row;
  }

  //setTimeout(() => this.tableData.paginator = this.paginator);

}
```

Notice how I've already tried many solutions involving assigning the paginator [image: but still the result given is this].

the html of the component:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableData">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.value}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="details">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail"> 
      <!--
      <app-test-table-detail [show]="detail.element == expandedElement" ></app-test-table-detail>
        -->
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"
    matRipple
    (click)="expand(row)"></tr>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['details']; when:isExpansionDetailRow"
    [@detailExpand]="row.element==expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
    style="overflow: hidden"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

interestingly, the paginator gives the correct numbers but have no effect, should I deal with it in the stream? in the connect function?

[edit]
latest code at stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulartableexample?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest-table%2Ftest-table.component.html

I also tried what the guy that deleted the comment recommends, which was to use AfterViewInit, also didn't work

[Edit]
by debugging a case that doesn't have this problem (without expandable rows) the difference is in this snippet of code, with expandable rows using my own version of DataSource there is no observers, but using the native there is, am I missing something in the definition of my data source?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that table in angular material is not that complete or flexible, so I resolved the problem with the use of native table tags and brute data processing. Native table is noted as a good alternative [in this angular material github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/10594) and [also here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5888)

I know it looks ugly, but solves the issue and as this component is only supposed to handle the table in a complete way (multiple column header + ordering + filtering + expandable row) as responsive as possible, the extra code inside the component isn't an issue.

I also used the paginator as a simple widget in the view giving paging data for the controller.

In the end, the component view is defined as:

```
<table class="mat-table" style="overflow-y:scrol">
  <thead>
    <tr class="mat-header-row">
      <th rowspan="2" class="mat-header-cell" (click)="orderBy('id')">
        ID
      </th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="1" class="mat-header-cell">
        But can you do this?
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mat-header-row">
      <th class="mat-header-cell" (click)="orderBy('name')">
        Name
      </th>
      <th class="mat-header-cell" (click)="orderBy('value')">
        Value
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let element of showData" (click)="expand(element)">
      <td class="mat-cell"  *ngIf="element.detailRow == undefined">
        {{element.id}}
      </td>
      <td class="mat-cell" *ngIf="element.detailRow == undefined">
        {{element.name}}
      </td>
      <td class="mat-cell" *ngIf="element.detailRow == undefined">
        {{element.value}}
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="mat-cell" *ngIf="element.detailRow">
        <app-test-table-detail [show]="true" [id]="element.element.id"></app-test-table-detail>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons (page)="applyPaging()"></mat-paginator>
```

and the controler, but the filtering is yet to be implemented

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TableRow } from './../table-row';
import { PageEvent, MatPaginator } from "@angular/material";
import { TestTableService } from './../test-table.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-native-table',
  templateUrl: './native-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./native-table.component.css']
})
export class NativeTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  private order : string = "id";
  private reverse : boolean;
  private cacheData : TableRow[] = [];
  private filteredData : TableRow[] = [];
  private pageData : TableRow[] = [];
  private showData : any[] = [];
  private selectedElement : TableRow;
  private filters : any = null;

  constructor(private tableService : TestTableService) { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.tableService.getData()
      .subscribe(table => this.cacheData = table);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.clearFilters();
  }

  clearFilters() : void{
    this.filters = {
      id : undefined,
      name : ""
    }
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter() : void{
    this.filteredData = this.cacheData.slice();
    //do filtering
    this.paginator.length = this.filteredData.length;
    this.applyOrder();
  }

  applyOrder() : void{
    this.filteredData.sort(this.orderRule(this.order,this.reverse))
    this.applyPaging();
  }

  applyPaging() : void{
    this.pageData = this.filteredData.slice(this.paginator.pageIndex*this.paginator.pageSize,(this.paginator.pageIndex+1)*this.paginator.pageSize);
    this.applySelected();
  }

  applySelected() : void{
    this.showData = [];
    this.pageData.forEach(element => element==this.selectedElement ? this.showData.push(element,{detailRow:true,element:element}) : this.showData.push(element))
  }

  orderBy(order : string) : void{
    if(this.order == order){
      this.reverse = !this.reverse
    }
    else{
      this.order = order;
      this.reverse = false;
    }

    this.applyOrder();
  }

  expand(element : TableRow) : void{
    this.selectedElement = this.selectedElement == element ? null : element;
    this.applySelected();
  }

  orderRule(onderIndex,reverse){
    return function(a,b){
      if(a[onderIndex] > b[onderIndex]){
        return reverse ? -1 : 1;
      }
      if(a[onderIndex] < b[onderIndex]){
        return reverse ? 1 : -1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

I've added a component to [the example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulartableexample), don't know why the @ViewChild return undefined for the paginator, but locally it does works as intended